# Why is na.rm not working in my code?

Tags: r, error-handling, na

I have a problem with removing NAs.

This is my code:

```
dataset <- read.csv2("my_file.csv", header = T)
year_order <- ret12[order(dataset$year, na.rm = T, decreasing = T), ]
# Returns:
#  *Error in order(ret12$year, na.rm = T, decreasing = T) :
#  argument lengths differ*
```

Why?

Comment: `order` does not offer an `na.rm` argument

Answer (score 0):

If you what to order and remove NA's marked by missing values in the ret12$year column (which would normally come last in the `order()`-ing), then you need to order, then omit:

```
 year.order <- ret12[ order(ret12$year, decreasing=T),][ 1:sum(!is.na(ret12)), ]
```